# Two columns divs inside a div container

Tags: html, css, layout

I would like to set the 2-columns divs with the same height than container (without using px of course)

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="hdr-lay">
    Header
    </div>

    <div id="left-column">
    Grid Layout left
    </div>

    <div id="right-column">
    Grid Layout right
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#hdr-lay {
    _background-color: red;
}

#container {
    background-color: gray;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#left-column {
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px;
    width: 70%;
}

#right-column {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g3gxv4j2/

Perhaps it would be easier to do itwith  no ?

Comment: are you facing issue when you're viewing this on small resolution..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like to set the 2-columns divs with the same height than
>   container

Since your container have `height:100%`, I assume you want the same for your child div's

- Give 100% height to your html and body

  ```
  html,body{
   height:100%
  }
  ```
- You've set `height:100%` for your container. This will only extend its height to 100% of its content(which themselves are not getting 100% height). Let your left and right columns *inherit height* from their parent container.

  ```
  #right-column {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  height:inherit;
  }

  #left-column {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px;
  width: 70%;
  height:inherit;
  }
  ```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nalinc/7newv8c2/)

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, that's what I need... But What is strange now is that the whole result is not  "inside" the browser window !? I guess because of the "header" section ?

Comment: Exactly! Thats because your left and right 'divs' are getting 100% height of their 'container' but the 'header' already occupies some portion of it

Comment: Ok, I think my mistake it to believe that a div is a "real" container for its child objet... I mean, unlike common GUI, there is no clipping, no overflow management (except overflow)

Answer (score 0):

This might be better :

```
#container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

#left-column {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#right-column {
  background-color: red;
  width: 70 %;
}
```